# Using views_embed_view() in View

Tags: views

I have created a View page, and added a "Global:PHP" field to embed a View block from another View using the following code:

```
<?php  print views_embed_view('VIEW_NAME','VIEW_BLOCK_NAME', $data->tid);?>
```

Now, it worked perfectly, but there's no detail or variables I can find in the print_r($data)/dsm($data) about this View block's content.

My purpose is that, if there's no result in view block, then I will hide a particular custom field. In short, "if views_embed_view() return empty then hide field A

Wondering how to go about it. Please advise. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I would instead use `views_get_view_result()` if all you are concerned with is if there is a result.  More information on it can be found [here](http://api.drupal.org/api/views/views.module/function/views_get_view_result/7).